# Exceptions of type "Message: JAR entry META-INF /services/* not found in /<service.jar>"

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a springboot based microservice that reads an XML from a SOAP endpoint, parses it and forwards the parsed response to requesting clients.

Below is the version of springboot/spring/tomcat used:

```html
<spring.boot.version>1.5.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
Tomcat 8.5.21.0
```

The service is functionally working fine and is able to handle load as well without much issues. But, when I look at the flight recording of the service, I see a lot of (~ million per min) exceptions of the type shown below:

```html
Stack Trace Count Percentage(%) Total
java.lang.Throwable.<init>(String) 1,532,051 95.618 0
   java.lang.Exception.<init>(String) 1,532,051 95.618 0
      java.io.IOException.<init>(String) 1,503,857 93.858 0
         java.io.FileNotFoundException.<init>(String) 1,503,782 93.854 0
            org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.throwFileNotFound(Object, JarFile) 1,503,782 93.854 0
               org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.connect() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                  org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                     sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(String, boolean) 1,503,782 93.854 0
                        sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.next() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                           sun.misc.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                              java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                 java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1.run() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext) 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                       java.net.URLClassLoader$3.next() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                          java.net.URLClassLoader$3.hasMoreElements() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                             sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                                sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                                   sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.next() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                                      sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                                         java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                                            java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                                               java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext() 1,503,782 93.854 0
                                                                  javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder$1.run() 1,046,435 65.31 0
                                                                     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction) 1,046,435 65.31 0
                                                                        javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(Class) 1,046,435 65.31 0
                                                                           javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(Class, String) 1,046,435 65.31 0
                                                                              javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance() 1,046,435 65.31 0
                                                                                 com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.<init>() 1,046,435 65.31 0
                                                                                    com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStreamingTransformer.newTransformer() 1,046,435 65.31 0
                                                                                       com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(OutputStream) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                          com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(OutputStream, boolean) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                             com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getContentAsStream() 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getHeaderBytes() 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges() 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                      org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.writeTo(OutputStream) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                         org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(WebServiceMessage) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                            org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceConnection, WebServiceMessage) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                               org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessageContext, WebServiceConnection, WebServiceMessageCallback, WebServiceMessageExtractor) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                                  org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(String, WebServiceMessageCallback, WebServiceMessageExtractor) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                                     org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(String, Object, WebServiceMessageCallback) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                                        org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(Object, WebServiceMessageCallback) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                                           org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(Object) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                                              com.hotels.booking.discos.loyalty.client.LoyaltyWebServiceGateway.sendAndReceive(AbstractLoyaltyRequest) 589,228 36.775 0
                                                                                                                                 com.hotels.booking.discos.loyalty.client.LoyaltyWebServiceGateway.retrieveRewardAdjustments(LoyaltyRewardAdjustmentsRetrievalRequest) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor334.invoke(Object, Object[]) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                          java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[]) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                             com.hotels.thermos.proxy.GenericProxyCircuitBreaker.execute() 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                com.hotels.thermos.AbstractCircuitBreaker.run() 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                   com.hotels.thermos.HystrixCommandWrapper.run() 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                      com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(Subscriber) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                         com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(Object) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                            rx.Observable$2.call(Subscriber) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                               rx.Observable$2.call(Object) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                                  rx.Observable$2.call(Subscriber) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                                     rx.Observable$2.call(Object) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                                        rx.Observable$2.call(Subscriber) 217,970 13.604 0
                                                                                                                                                                           rx.Observable$2.call(Object) 217,970 13.604 0
```

The specific exceptions seems to be:

```html
Message: JAR entry META-INF /services/* not found in /<service.jar>
```

[image]

[image]

The number of exceptions puts a lot of memory pressure on the service, limiting the performance/scalability of the service

I tried looking for solutions to this and found a few similar issues. Most resources point to embedded tomcat as the issue. But I could not find the reason or solution for this specific issue anywhere.

Any help understanding/resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: <spring.boot.version>1.5.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring.version>4.2.7.RELEASE</spring.version>

Spring.version is old. Release date is 2016 so you can upgrade it also you are using Hystrix as I know you have to use java 1.8 at least

Comment: Hi @Gurkanİlleez Thanks for your response. It appears like the spring version I mentioned is not the one we're using. We are using springboot 1.5.4, which in turn uses Spring 4.3.9. The additional spring version entry in the pom was unused and the cause of confusion. Sorry about that. I have updated the original description with the correct version now.